# android:launchMode="singleTask" affect install

Tags: android, cordova

I have an app that allows users to download an updated apk.  Once downloaded, the new apk is installed.  What I expected was:

1. the installation dialog opens asking the user if they want to
   install, etc.
2. the installation completes and asks the user if they
   want to open the app.

Instead, after the first step the dialog disappears/closes.  If I relaunch the app manually I can see that the version has updated successfully and the app works as expected.  The downloaded update is being directed to `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory` so there shouldn't be a problem with permissions.  The only other thing I can think of is that the app has the application attribute `android:launchMode="singleTask"` which was included to prevent a user from launching another instance of the app (a necessary functionality).

Might the problem be the 'launchMode' attribute?  If so, is there a work around?

[ADDITIONAL INFO]  My symptoms are [identical to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569647/android-programmatically-update-apk-and-see-the-result-of-the-installation).  I haven't yet had success with the proposed solution.

[SOLVED] This answer is 'launchMode' is not a factor, the download directory is.  The explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905237/cordova-android-programmatic-install-fails-without-error).

Comment: `android:launchMode="singleTask" which was included to prevent multiple instances` - not exactly.

Comment: Not sure what you mean; see my edit.