# How to install any Android app programmatically in Android 10

Tags: android, android-intent

**In Android 9 & 10**
I face issued in install app programmatically in Android Studio using filepath  apk file.
Below show what I tried..

```java
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app-release.apk"), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

I also added required permission in manifest file .

When I run this then it give me **There was a problem parsing the package** error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the entire stack trace.

Comment: I not get any exception or error in logcat.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want install application programmatically in Android 10, You need to give permission to install app for your application

Steps 1: Give permission in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Step 2: Write provider in Android Manifest

```
 <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Step 4: Create file in XML folder named as provider_paths.xml and write

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="files_root"
        path="Android/data/${applicationId}" />
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

step 4: Give runtime permission for apk installation and storage permissions

```
    //installtion permission

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                if (!getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES).setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getPackageName()))), 1234);
                } else {
                }
    }

    //Storage Permission

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            }

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
```

Step 5: Call install apk function

```
 void installAPK(){

    String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "apkname.apk";
    File file = new File(PATH);
    if(file.exists()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uriFromFile(getApplicationContext(), new File(PATH)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        try {
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("TAG", "Error in opening the file!");
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"installing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
Uri uriFromFile(Context context, File file) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
    } else {
        return Uri.fromFile(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly i need this

Comment: ACTION_VIEW is deprecated in android 10

Answer (score 8):

First, your `Uri` is invalid on every version of Android, outside of a few devices where the device manufacturer hacked in something for you.

Second, by default, neither you nor the package installer process have access to external storage on Android 10.

Third, installing apps via `ACTION_VIEW` or `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` is deprecated on Android 10.

The solution for Android 10 and higher — which also works on Android 5.0 and higher — is to [use `PackageInstaller`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller).

[This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/vFINAL/AppInstaller) demonstrates how to use it. The key pieces are in `MainMotor`:

```
/*
  Copyright (c) 2019 CommonsWare, LLC

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  Covered in detail in the book _Elements of Android Q

  https://commonsware.com/AndroidQ
*/

package com.commonsware.q.appinstaller

import android.app.Application
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageInstaller
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

private const val NAME = "mostly-unused"
private const val PI_INSTALL = 3439

class MainMotor(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
  private val installer = app.packageManager.packageInstaller
  private val resolver = app.contentResolver

  fun install(apkUri: Uri) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
      installCoroutine(apkUri)
    }
  }

  private suspend fun installCoroutine(apkUri: Uri) =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      resolver.openInputStream(apkUri)?.use { apkStream ->
        val length =
          DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(getApplication(), apkUri)?.length() ?: -1
        val params =
          PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL)
        val sessionId = installer.createSession(params)
        val session = installer.openSession(sessionId)

        session.openWrite(NAME, 0, length).use { sessionStream ->
          apkStream.copyTo(sessionStream)
          session.fsync(sessionStream)
        }

        val intent = Intent(getApplication(), InstallReceiver::class.java)
        val pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
          getApplication(),
          PI_INSTALL,
          intent,
          PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        session.commit(pi.intentSender)
        session.close()
      }
    }
}
```

Here, `install()` is given a `Uri` from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. Inside of a coroutine, I create a `PackageInstaller` session, open the session, copy the APK contents to a session-supplied stream, then commit and close the session.

Comment: @Ak23: Sorry, but I do not have any `PackageInstaller` sample Java code available.

Comment: Any idea about auto start app after install completed?

Comment: @Ak23 There are quite a few ways to go about it, depending on your needs. You can  use `PackageManager` and `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` or if you already know the parameters, you would simply define a new intent. I would recommend looking for that as a separate question.

Comment: @AbandonedCart Can you explain bit more about getLaunchIntentForPackage() i have a same problem as @Ak23?

Comment: @shakil.k A quick Google search for `getLaunchIntentForPackage` brings up the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)) on it. It is going to require some investment on your part.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the intent stuff send to the session.commit call. And so far I can't find any documentation on it other than Google's Android manual, which doesn't give an example and assumes you know what it is and why it's there, etc.  Could you speak a bit about that, or point me to someplace that does? Thanks!

Comment: @Bungles: "point me to someplace that does" -- I cover that example in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Q). `commit()` takes an `IntentSender`, and usually we get one of those from a `PendingIntent`. That will be where we find out if the install succeeds, fails, or needs user approval. The [`InstallReceiver`](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/blob/vFINAL/AppInstaller/src/main/java/com/commonsware/q/appinstaller/InstallReceiver.kt) in my sample app beeps on success, starts the approval activity if that's needed, and otherwise logs a message to Logcat.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have tried your code for updating apk using PackageInstaller,  It works but after the app updated successfully it restart whole app, And user have to go and click on app from recent screen or launcher to bring app back to foreground.

Comment: @shakil.k: Updating an app will require its process to be terminated, so what you are describing sounds correct. `PackageInstaller` and older methods are not designed for an app to update itself, but instead for something else (e.g., an app distribution channel client, like F-Droid) to update another app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any way i can restart my app after it updates. I am currently using MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED receiver to launch my app again, but for android 10+ app can't launch because of background restrictions.

Comment: @shakil.k: "Is there any way i can restart my app after it updates" -- none that I know of.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```